# Pub/Sub to BigQuery (Batch) using Dataflow (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I created a streaming Dataflow pipeline in Python and just want to clarify if my below code is doing what I expected. This is what I intend to do :

1. Consume from Pub/Sub continuously
2. Batch load into BigQuery every 1 minute instead of streaming to bring down the cost

This is the code snippet in Python

```
options = PipelineOptions(
    subnetwork=SUBNETWORK,
    service_account_email=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    use_public_ips=False,
    streaming=True,
    project=project,
    region=REGION,
    staging_location=STAGING_LOCATION,
    temp_location=TEMP_LOCATION,
    job_name=f"pub-sub-to-big-query-xxx-{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')}"
)

p = beam.Pipeline(DataflowRunner(), options=options)


pubsub = (
        p
        | "Read Topic" >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=INPUT_TOPIC)
        | "To Dict" >> Map(json.loads)
        | "Write To BigQuery" >> WriteToBigQuery(table=TABLE, schema=schema, method='FILE_LOADS',
                                                 triggering_frequency=60, max_files_per_bundle=1,
                                                 create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                 write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
```

May I know if the above code is doing what I intend it to do? Stream from Pub/Sub and at every 60 seconds, it will batch insert into BigQuery. I purposely set the **max_files_per_bundle** to **1** to prevent more than 1 shard being created so that there is only 1 file being loaded every minute but not sure if I am doing it right. There is withNumFileShards option for Java version but I could not find the equivalent in Python. I refer to the documentation below:
https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.31.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-efficiently-process-both-real-time-and-aggregate-data-with-dataflow

Just curious if I should use windowing to achieve what I intend to do?

```
options = PipelineOptions(
    subnetwork=SUBNETWORK,
    service_account_email=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    use_public_ips=False,
    streaming=True,
    project=project,
    region=REGION,
    staging_location=STAGING_LOCATION,
    temp_location=TEMP_LOCATION,
    job_name=f"pub-sub-to-big-query-xxx-{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')}"
)

p = beam.Pipeline(DataflowRunner(), options=options)

pubsub = (
        p
        | "Read Topic" >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=INPUT_TOPIC)
        | "To Dict" >> Map(json.loads)
        | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60), trigger=AfterProcessingTime(60),
                                      accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
        | "Write To BigQuery" >> WriteToBigQuery(table=TABLE, schema=schema, method='FILE_LOADS',
                                                 triggering_frequency=60, max_files_per_bundle=1,
                                                 create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                 write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
```

The first method is good enough without the windowing in second method? I am using the first method now but I am not sure if every minute, it's **doing multiple load from multiple files or it actually merge all the pub/sub message into 1 and do a single bulk load?**

Thank you!

Comment: Windows are used when you need to perform some aggregation in your data, as described [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing). In addition, if you are using a streaming pipeline you should stream data to BigQuery because when setting `triggering_frequency=60` you will surpass the maximum amount of load jobs per table per day , see [Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs). If you want to use batch load you need to exemplify more how your data is streamed to Pub/Sub. Also, it is good to mention that GCS to BigQuery is free of charge.

Comment: Lastly, could you tell me if you ran your pipeline and checked the output in  BigQuery?

Comment: Hello @AlexandreMoraes , the daily limit per table is 1500, I am loading it every minute, so will be 60*24 = 1440 which is still below the 1500 per day. Actually I do not need to do any aggregation, it's more on I want to merge all the files every minute. My script is sending messages in json to Pub/Sub after it parse every file in GCS. Theoretically, I can send my output to GCS but it would be a bit too slow to kick start dataflow job every minute or so. Unless I create another script that send message to Pub/Sub every minute which trigger the batch loading in the streaming dataflow job.

Comment: For data with low number of Pub/Sub message every minute, my pipeline is working fine without the windowing method. But when there is a lot pub/sub messages every minute, I keep encountering this error. My table is partitioned by a date column. 
Error Result: <ErrorProto message: 'Failed to copy Non partitioned table to Column partitioned table: not supported.' reason: 'invalid'> [while running 'Write To BigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/ParDo(TriggerCopyJobs)/ParDo(TriggerCopyJobs)-ptransform-46459'] passed through: ==> dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/fnapi_service_impl.cc:644

Comment: I suppose all the files are not actually being merged and loaded into BigQuery every minute based on my current implementation. Not sure if that is because Python version of dataflow doesn't have the functionality or there is something that I miss out. Appreciate your advice and help!

Comment: It looks like this is copying from a non-partitioned table to a column-partitioned table, which should be disallowed. Is that full error? Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Hello @PjoterS my table is a date column partitioned table and I actually inserted it from memory into the table itself. I ended up using Java version to achieve what I need to achieve instead. I suppose the Python version is not as stable as I would expect for Dataflow.

Comment: So you were able to solve your issue by changing python to java? Could you share your solution?

Comment: Hello @PjoterS sorry I miss your question.I have posted the solution I use in Java version

Answer (score 1):

Not the python solution, but I resort to Java version in the end

```
public static PTransform<PCollection<String>, PCollection<TableRow>> jsonToTableRow() {
    return new JsonToTableRow();
}

private static class JsonToTableRow
        extends PTransform<PCollection<String>, PCollection<TableRow>> {

    @Override
    public PCollection<TableRow> expand(PCollection<String> stringPCollection) {
        return stringPCollection.apply("JsonToTableRow", MapElements.via(
                new SimpleFunction<String, TableRow>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableRow apply(String json) {
                        try {
                            InputStream inputStream =
                                    new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                            return TableRowJsonCoder.of().decode(inputStream, Context.OUTER);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to parse input", e);
                        }
                    }
                }));
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);
    options.setStreaming(true);
    options.setDiskSizeGb(10);

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    pipeline.apply("Read from PubSub", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic()))
            .apply(jsonToTableRow())
            .apply("WriteToBigQuery", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(options.getOutputTable())
                    .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS)
                    .withTriggeringFrequency(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
                    .withNumFileShards(1)
                    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
    pipeline.run();
```